# Is there an efficient way to create unique styles for each page?

Tags: meteor

Meteor template are great for different data in the same style.

What if thousands of pages have to have their own style? I assume this will require all pages to have their own template.

For example, how could I store and fetch javascript animations?

Is there any easy way to do this or do they have to be individual template files?

Comment: What does the style (fonts, alignment, colors, formatting, layout) have to do with storing/calling JS animations? Could you perhaps clarify your question.

Comment: @noumenal   Well, CSS will probably be the same for all pages. For example,`h1` font size will be the same on every page but page components such as different amount of page title, animations, paragraphs, sometimes a section of the page is divided into two columns etc. Right now, all I know is when I put `{{title}}` into certain position of the HTML to fetch title from Mongo, it applies to all pages.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to customize the style of pages dynamically (using JS) by using the package `ccorcos:reactive-css`.  It lets you create CSS style sheets using JavaScript and using that you can adjust it depending on what page is being shown, or what data is coming from the DB.

You could even generate JS animations on the fly.

Comment: That's pretty cool. Thanks! But how do you store page-specific values? Think about thousands of different page styles?

Comment: depends what you need.... but you could easily have a Pages collection that has a `style` key that has your custom style per page.